# Still I'm getting error even after restart and adding the line to gradle Properties file

Tags: android

**> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.**

//This is the error can anyone solve this error.

Comment: Is there any error in any of your xml files

Comment: Could you please clarify your question; I.e. explain what you try to do, share some relevant code, explain what you have tried so far? Also, the error mentions: check the logs for details, could you share the log output?

Comment: @RaBaKa78 no There is no error in xml or java